# Tagging as trained and certified

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I have list of employee ids who are required to complete all 4 courses. I have an identifier column which is trained and contains 1 if the course is completed. Now I need to tag them as certified if they have completed all courses and the score for their course 1 >= 80.

User

| employe_id | Course_name | final_score | Status | Trained |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | course_1 | 85 | completed | 1 |
| 10 | course_2 | 80 | completed | 1 |
| 10 | course_3 | 90 | completed | 1 |
| 10 | course_4 | 95 | completed | 1 |
| 20 | course_1 | 70 | completed | 1 |
| 20 | course_2 | 80 | subscribed | 1 |
| 20 | course_3 | 97 | subscribed | 1 |
| 20 | course_4 | 60 | completed | 1 |

In this case I should only get 1. How can I do it in a measure?

I tried several countrows measure however when I validated the data I get some who have a passing score in course 1 but not completed the other 3.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is a `Group BY` in M, the idea is to create to column so that you can compare the sum of all your scores and the number of courses taken:

```
= Table.Group(#"YOUR_TABLE", {"employe_id"}, {{"Sum", each List.Sum([final_score]), type nullable number}, {"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}})
```

now we can compare `Sum` and `count` in DAX (create a new column):

```
Status = IF('Table'[Sum] >= 80* 'Table'[Count],"completed","Failed")
```

You can also use a measure, a query would be like:

```
Status = IF(sum('Your Table'[final_score]) >= 80 * COUNT('Your Table'[Status]),"Completed","Failed")
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without any changes to your data model. First create a measure which identifies individuals as certified or not:

```
Is Certified =
VAR _score_course1 =
    CALCULATE (
        SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[final_score] ),
        'Table'[Course_name] = "course_1"
    )
VAR _incomplete =
    CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( 'Table' ), 'Table'[Status] <> "completed" )
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        NOT HASONEVALUE ( 'Table'[employee_id] ), BLANK (),
        _incomplete = 0 && _score_course1 >= 80, "Certified",
        "Not certified"
    )
```

Then, when the measure framework for establishing individuals as certified is in place, add a new measure with simple iteration over employee_id `VALUES` to determine a proper count:

```
Certified Count = 
SUMX ( 
    VALUES ( 'Table'[employee_id] ) , 
    IF ( [Is Certified] = "Certified" , 1 )
)
```

The result here, with the first measure in a simple table visual, and the second measure in a card:

[image]